# Optimization: large MySQL table, only recent records used

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an optimization question.

The PHP web application, that I have recently started working with, has several large database tables in a MySQL database. The information in this tables should be accessible at all times for business purposes, which makes them grow really big eventually.

The tables are regularly written to and recent records are frequently selected.

Previous developers came up with a very weird practice of optimizing the system. They created separate database for storing recent records in order to keep tables compact and sync the tables once the record grows "old" (more than 24 hours old).

The application uses current date to pick the right database, when performing a SELECT query.

This is a very weird solution in my opinion. We had a big argument over that and I am looking to change this. However, before, I decided to ask:

1) Has someone ever came across anything similar before? I mean, separate database for recent records.

2) What are the most common practices to optimize databases for this particular case?

Any opinions are welcome, as there are many ways one can go at this point.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to purge the old records that are no longer used?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, they should all be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using INDEX:

[CREATE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

That improve the access, use and deploy of the information.

Comment: Upon doing some further research, I've realized, that INDEX was actually the thing, that previous developers did not know about :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could help you [RANGE Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html)

Comment: Why, how it helps, how it works, what is hidden behind the link, what is the core information on that site, is your answer useful even if the link is broken or no longer exist? Read it pls: [answer]

Comment: I forgot to mention, that records are stored in a "recent" database every 24 hours. So, even if I fully automate partitioning, I do not think, that creating a new one every day is particularly good.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do a Partion to the table base on a date range.
By splitting a large table into smaller, individual tables, queries that access only a fraction of the data can run faster because there is less data to scan. Maintenance tasks, such as rebuilding indexes or backing up a table, can run more quickly.

The documentation of Mysql can be useful, check this out :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-range.html